# Changing a number when a call ends

Tags: android

I'm developing an application which works with number those being called -- it changes them. After a call ends, I want to changed a number which is called and an user will see a changed number in "Call log".

The **reason** I want to do that is that my applications adds a prefix for an outgoing call and when a call ends I want an user to be able to see who they just called without seeing a prefix. Otherwise, if a number will come to a Call Log with a prefix, they won't be able to do that -- an Android won't recognize this number as a number which exists in Phone Book (assuming it does). So it's just a user convenience.

How do I do that?

Comment: Sounds like something that should be completely forbidden for security reasons and wouldn't give much hope in finding solution.

Comment: Yeah - this question sounds like a lawyer/cops/TLA magnet.  OP - you should remove it. (and possibly assume a new identity).

Comment: @MartinJames, no, my main man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html. 
You must implementing a BroadcastReceiver for catch up when call was ended. After that you may change the call number with update() Method. CallLog takes information from ContentProvider linked with contacts.

So I got a missed call, and the name. After i changed CallState of the read.
This is an example how to get missed calls count.

```
private int getUnreadCallsCount()
{
    if (c != null)
    {
        c.close();
        c = null;
    }
    String[] projection = { CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, CallLog.Calls.TYPE };
    StringBuilder where = new StringBuilder();
    where.append(Calls.NEW);
    where.append(" = 1 AND ");
    where.append(Calls.TYPE);
    where.append(" = ");
    where.append(Calls.MISSED_TYPE);
    c = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, where.toString(), null, null);
    if (c != null)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c.getCount();
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: what should I get from there?